# Simulate GPS speed and heading on Android Emulator

Tags: android, geolocation, cordova

Im trying to test my phonegap gps location application on Android Emulator.

I need to simulate W3C gps speed and heading on Android Emulator http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html.

Using DDMS i was able to setup kml path. However navigation.watchPosition only see latitude and longitude changes, heading and speed parameters are undefined.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the android emulator, I use the ripple extension in chrome as the emulator. You can change everything you need for geolocation with it.